# "Connection lost" after response and status received

Tags: ios, network-programming, ios7, nsurlconnection

We've published an iPhone app consisting of a client pointed to a JSON API.

Calling out to this endpoint seems to work fine 99% of the time, but for requests which generate a sufficiently long response body, we get an error:

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)"

However, the returned statusCode is 200, and the response data has been completely received!

We only see this behavior on iOS 7, not iOS 6.  There are no errors in the server's application or Apache logs to suggest that it's aware of any problem at its end.  If it were a real network connectivity issue, we would not expect it to occur 100% of the time for responses over a certain length and 0% for other responses.

Does anyone know what causes this behavior, or can anyone offer debugging suggestions?

Comment: We are encountering the same issues, are you using sendSynchronousRequest or sendASynchronousRequest as well? I've talked with other developers that use the delegate approach and they aren't encountering the issue

Comment: We're using the MPOAuth library, which does indeed use sendSynchronousRequest (it subclasses NSURLConnection).